# Rutishauser's LR algorithm for finding the eigenvalues of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I write `C++` program for finding the eigenvalues of the matrix using `LR` algorithm. My question is more about algorithm. For finding coefficient of $L$ matrix, I divide $A$ by $R$, where $A$ is coefficient of initial matrix and $R$ is coefficient of $R$ matrix.

$r_{1k} = a_{1k} \quad k = 1 \ldots n $

$ l_{i,i-1} = a_{i,i-1}/ r_{i-1,i-1}  \quad i = 2\ldots n $

$ r_{i,k} = a_{i,k} - l_{i,i-1}\cdot r_{i-1,k}  \quad k \geq i > 1,  \quad  i,k = 2\ldots n $

What should I do in the situation when $R$ is zero.

In this algorithm, initial matrix $A_{m}=L_{m}R_{m}$. In the next stage $A_{m+1} = R_{m}L_{m}$. This matrix has same eigenvalues for $m\rightarrow \infty$. In this moment $a_{t,t-1}$ (value of matrix is to left from main diagonal ) should converge to zero. (Finding starts with the last element standing on main diagonal). But in some case $a_{t,t-1}$ diverges. Why does it happen?